# Ignore Case with apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, webserver

I have a website where I was forced to move over a bunch of pdf files from a windows server and many of the files have capitalization.  This of course shows a file not found if someone has a link going to the file without the correct case.   Its a big problem since my client has a many links pointing to these files with a myriad of case options.

I have enabled the speling module in apache and it seems to have helped with ignoring case for urls but NOT FOR THE PDFs.

Does anyone have a work around for this?

I followed these instructions for enabling the speling module: http://keystoneit.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/making-apache-case-insensitive/

Answer (score 0):

As it's a file system feature under *nix boxes rather than apache specifically, you can batch rename all your pdf files to small case using shell or using some server-side scripting language and can

redirect all non-matching pdf requests to a guidelines page using *htaccess* where you can inform the user to type small case letters for the pdf file and also

you can give him download link with lowercase letters for the filename extracted from the url..